# Axiom - what does this statement about the “truth” of axioms mean?

Tags: axioms

When reading the [Axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom#cite_ref-5) page on Wikipedia, I encountered this sentence at the end of the lead:

> Whether it is meaningful (and, if so, what it means) for an axiom,
>   or any mathematical statement, **to be "true" is an open
>   question<sup>[citation needed]</sup>** in the philosophy of mathematics.[5]

I would appreciate if minds more knowledgeable than me in this direction, could elaborate what the above sentence  means? (especially the part in bold).

Comment: It means we do not discuss much whether axioms are true. Only what their consequences are.

Comment: Suggested reading : Morris Kline, [Mathematics: The Loss of Certainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics:_The_Loss_of_Certainty) (1980). The background is the human need for "certainty": form Euclid and Aristotle, mathematics was the paradigmatic case of certainty, based on the deduction (by way of logical tools) from certain principles : the axioms. From 19th Century, things became "more complicated"...

Comment: Giorgi: could you link us to the passage you quote?  I looked through [this entry "Axiom" in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom).  It would be great if you could provide the source/location of your highlighted statement.

Comment: @amWhy: sure last paragraph in introductory section; try searching too using keyword

Comment: @user2003300  I've carefully read through Wikipedia's entry "Axiom".  I have put a lot of time in trying to address answerers, as well as to understand in what context you found your quote.  If you can provide the link to that quote, I'd really appreciate it.  Otherwise, take care of your sources,  or phrases **to be "true" is an open question** which has no citation so we know who is claiming this.

Comment: @amWhy It is in the Wikipedia page for "Axiom" at the end of the fourth paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

Being very macroscopic... Doing mathematics consists in:

- **Admitting** axioms.
- **Admitting** déduction rules
- **Deducing** *conclusions* from *premises* using *axioms* and *déduction rules*.

A proof consists in doing this deduction the right way. I mean ensuring that the set of axioms is used properly and the same for the  deduction rules.

**The question of understanding if the axioms are the right ones is not a Mathematical question.**

This opens by the way an interesting question... What means being the right ones? This question is closely related to the question are those axioms true or not that you raised.

Comment: If axioms are not true in some "reasonable" sense of *truth*, what is the relevance of the "proof" of e.g. [Fermat's Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_Last_Theorem) ? What does it mean the Theorem ? If math is only "doing this deduction the right way" it seems a sort of gymnastics, or a sort of "zen discipline"...

Comment: Look at what happened in history with the [Parallel postulate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate) and the creation of Euclidean geometry. This seemed to be a "true" axiom. And later other geometries were created with different axioms.

Comment: Agreed ... and the *elliptical geometry* is true on the sphere.

Comment: A very good book in French (I don't know an existing English translation) is [Matière à penser](https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B00BJAEU0G/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1), which is a dialog between the neurobiologist Jean-Pierre Changeux and the Mathematician Alain Connes. The background of the book is about the question of Mathematics vs. Truth and reality.

Comment: [Conversations on Mind, Matter, and Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=QnBdhJbfqOAC&pg=PR4).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks Mauro for the link to the English translation!

Comment: mathematics $\neq$ admitting which axioms, and why, and by whom?  ...admitting which deduction rules, and why and by whom?...deducing conclusions from premises using which axioms? and which déduction rules?  You haven't clarified in *any way whatsoever* what mathematics is as apart from many other disciplines.  Your answer amounts to "hand-waving" the question away.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I read it as questioning whether mathematics is really just a human construct, and questioning as to whether or not mathematics is "real" and "meaningful", which I'll admit is vague wording. But I think what the line is questioning is whether or not mathematics is in existence, so to speak, outside of our minds. People argue both ways on this; I personally believe that there is "more" to math than just human scribbles on a piece of paper.

It also somewhat questions whether or not our starting "principles" if you will, are correct, which is another fair question that is more difficult. However, I think this one depends directly on the first question. If math isn't "real" then our axioms can (theoretically) be whatever we want them to be. If math is indeed, more than just a human construct, then again, theoretically, there could be a "right" way and a "wrong" way, so then we wonder whether our axioms are correct.

Another thing to consider: how do we define "true"? One could define it as self-consistent, that is, no part of math contradicting itself, which math certainly is. We don't write that 2+2=4 over here and 2+2=5 over there. Or we could define it as something beyond just self-consistent, but having some meaning beyond writing in books and papers. It is the latter that this sentence is questioning, I believe. This then brings us back to the first paragraph of this answer.

I hope that makes sense; if it doesn't, let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Well if we don't know what it means for mathematical statement to be true, I find it surprising that so much research has been done in math still

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava, perhaps I didn't explain clearly. How do we define "true"? One could define it as self-consistent, which math certainly is. Or we could define it as something beyond just self-consistent, but having some meaning beyond writing in books and papers. It is the latter that this sentence is questioning, I believe.

Comment: Heather, this question isn't strictly about constructivism vs. Platonism.

Comment: @amWhy, not strictly, I suppose, no. I think this is a legitimate answer though. Or what is wrong?

Comment: Thanks for effort but I have a feeling this hasn't shed too much light for me on this subject

Comment: if you don't know what it means for math statement to be true why would you waste time doing and researching it then? that is my question

Comment: @amWhy Yes, exactly - maybe you could shed more light

Comment: @user200300 You may want to think about this as "mathematical truth means some statement has been derived from axioms using a given set of deduction rules". Now, a number of axioms appear to be self-evident and are usually considered as "true", but that is a different matter.

Comment: @user200300 To quote philosopher Bertrand Russel : “Pure mathematics consists entirely of assertions to the effect that, if such and such a proposition is true of anything, then such and such another proposition is true of that thing. It is essential not to discuss whether the first proposition is really true, and not to mention what the anything is, of which it is supposed to be true. [...] Thus mathematics may be defined as the subject in which we never know what we are talking about, nor whether what we are saying is true.”

Comment: Once again, A.G., I ask:  Bertrand Russell was first and foremost a logician. He has also been embraced as one philosopher for historical purposes.  Quoting him may reveal your own philosophy of mathematics, and likely his.  How does this answer the question?

Comment: @amWhy, in the last paragraph I address what it means for a mathematical statement to be "true" and then in earlier paragraphs discuss the implications of that.

Comment: @user200300., well, I said there are two definitions of what it means for a math statement to be true; one of which is certainly true, and one which is more for debate. this doesn't mean that there is no definition at all; there is one definition for sure.

Comment: Heather, I think your answer is fine.  The quoted statement was certainly vague, with no context given,

Answer (score 1):

I think the debate is does the truth of whether or not the axioms of math are absolutely "true" matters as much as how useful they are in describing the world and predicting things. Even if the axioms of math were proven to be false, they can still be useful as approximations to reality, just as Newtonian Gravity is a useful approximation to General Relativity. **As long as the axioms of math are consistent, can be used to model reality (not just Physics), and there is no better system in place,** does it really matter if the axioms are not justified? Also, I forgot to mention the case in which **doing math is pleasing**, like pure math, in which case I would argue that it still serves a purpose in that it pleases people. Also, pure math often ends up having applications in the real world, much to the chagrin of pure mathematicians. Hardy, for instance, bragged about how nothing he did had any value. His work, however has been used in both evolutionary biology and quantum physics.

Comment: I don't think the questions is satisfactorily  answered through a utilitarian argument.

Comment: I don't think your analogy really matches the case in Mathematics. If we found that 2+2<4 is a useful approximation to the reality of 2+2 and we accepted the statement as true then it would create an inconsistency and we could deduce any statement within that logical system.

Comment: @Hugh I was talking more about the fact that whether or not math is objectively true, it is an approximation to reality that can be useful. His question is whether or not it is meaningful for the axioms of math to be true. My response is a pragmatist response--that it really isn't meaningful for math to be objectively true so long as we can use it to do things that we want to do. Plus, I said nothing about the system itself being inconsistent, merely that it may not perfectly model reality and therefore not be objectively true.

Comment: I think you're mixing up *physics* and *mathematics*, AlgorithmsX

Comment: @amWhy Fair point, though I would say that I am probably combining applied mathematics and pure mathematics, as you could extend my argument to graph theory, algorithms, etc.

Comment: physics aspires to model/explain reality, and uses as a tool, mathematics.  But even physicists realize that mathematics is hugely bigger than what is  useful.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX I see your point but now I'm curious, when you talk about modeling reality I presume you don't mean something like using math about parabolas to model the path of a stone that I threw. The stone doesn't follow an exact parabola so the math can only be applied as an approximation, but this doesn't make the mathematical truths we deduce about parabolas to be less true. Even if there exist no true parabolas physically then we can still have mathematically true statements about parabolas given their definition + other axioms. So what did you mean by approximating reality?

Comment: @Hugh Basically, I'm arguing that even if mathematics was not objectively true, we would still use it **if no better system was in place** to model situations. We may not have perfect parabolas in throwing stones, but we do have perfect parabolas in things such as determining the number of handshakes at a party given a group of people (Graph Theory) or how many elements should be used to make a triangle (Triangular Numbers). Also, when I say "model reality", I'm not just talking about Physics, but also things like Computer Science, Chemistry, etc.

Comment: @amWhy Not just physics, and I think my answer gives the reason why the Wiki article questions whether or not it is meaningful for the axioms to be justified. **Does it matter if math is objectively true if it can be useful or (I neglected this earlier) pleasing?**

Comment: @AlgorithmsX Thanks for elaborating

Comment: @Hugh Sorry about that, I should have gone into more detail in the first place. I'll see if I can't add more to my answer.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX  I'm still trying to confirm for myself what the source of the OP's "quote" is, (and anyway, any claim it about "truth in math" has yet to be cited or attributed to any specific person, school of thought)...etc,   But mathematics is not equivalent to any other sciences.  That other sciences have advanced from progress in mathematics may be true...  But it is more that what can be applied now;

Answer (score 1):

"Open question" in the above statement is not in the sense used in mathematics (e.g. "[Collatz conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) is an open question."), rather it means "open to debate".

I believe the [etymology of the word "axiom"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=axiom&allowed_in_frame=0) leads one in the correct direction. Even though we have axioms precisely because we can, saying that they appear out of the blue is not completely accurate.

I recommend you to take a look at Wigner's essay "The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences" and Mac Lane's *Mathematics: Form and Function*.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, just to cover all my bases: an *open question* is a question that is not yet considered resolved by the academic community.

As for the rest: The "truth" of an axiom is a sticky subject. A famous example is the Axiom of Choice; I won't go into the details of the axiom (Wikipedia can give you a pretty good sketch of it) but the important thing is that it really only talks about infinite sets.

With many axioms, we can say they're "true" because they accurately match what actually happens - for example, consider the axiom "every integer has a successor". We could argue that it's "true" because whenever we have a collection of objects, we can add one more. The problem is, when an axiom only talks about *infinite* objects, we can't point to any such physical objects.

It seems like in order to say that an axiom is "true", we have to suppose that the things it talks about *actually physically exist*. This is a *wildly* problematic supposition, since according to modern developments in set theory there are infinitely many possible mathematical "universes", all of which behave quite differently but are indistinguishable when it comes to the everyday finite sets we actually encounter. Which one are we in? If they all have the same consequences in the finite world, why does it even matter which one we're in?

Which means that the best way to classify an axiom as "true" or "false" is probably just "does it seem sensible?" The problem is, the Axiom of Choice is something that most people, on a first reading, would consider obviously true; but it has truly bizarre consequences, like the Banach-Tarski paradox, which the average person on the street would say is obviously false. So while the Axiom of Choice "makes sense" and so should be "true", its consequences don't "make sense" and so should be "false".

The solution to this whole business that has been generally agreed-upon among modern mathematicians is to just ignore it - who cares if an axiom is "true"? Instead, we concentrate on "consistent" or "inconsistent", which are qualities we can precisely define, or we just look at the interesting consequences of the axiom.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments on other answers I think you are too focused on one type of knowledge. In mathematics (and deductive logic in general) when we take axioms like:

- Max is a dog
- All dogs have tails

And deduce a conclusion, in this case :

- Max has a tail

Of course these axioms are very questionable, maybe Max is a human or maybe some dogs have no tails. The point is that mathematics isn't telling us the "Max has a tail" is in itself true, mathematics is telling us "If you accept these two axioms then the conclusion is true". This is a different form of knowledge but one that is still valuable.

It's true that in some cases these axioms aren't true and we can't know that the conclusion is true. This is like when we develop mathematics for $x$ being a natural number but later we learn that $x$ is a real number. Even so, what we know is the conclusions given the axioms.

Answer (score 0):

#### Summary

What you highlighted is not an independent part of the sentence. The sentence says that philosophers disagree about what it means to say that statements like “*0 is a number*” or “*two plus two is four*” are true. There are indeed many competing [schools of thought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mathematics#Contemporary_schools_of_thought).

#### Your question

You ask what this sentence from the Wikipedia article *[Axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom)* means:

> Whether it is meaningful (and, if so, what it means) for an axiom, or any mathematical statement, to be "true" is an open question in the philosophy of mathematics.

In the [*version as of 2016-11-22*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Axiom&oldid=750909627), this statement occurs at the end of the introductory section, i.e. the end of the fourth paragraph, immediately before the section heading [*“Etymology”*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom#Etymology).

Your are particularly interested in this part:

> to be "true" is an open question<sup>[citation needed]</sup>

- <sup>‘*[citation needed]*’</sup> means that someone felt that the statement needed backing up by a reference to an appropriate source.
- ‘*to be "true" is an open question*’ cannot very well be isolated as a constituent of the sentence, which should be read as ‘{Whether it is meaningful … for an axiom … to be “true”} is {an open question in the philosophy of mathematics}’

#### Analysis of the sentence

I shall try to reformulate, rearrange and explain the sentence in question:

> In the philosophy of mathematics

I.e. we are not talking about mathematics in the sense of setting up theories and solving problems; we are talking about trying to understand the significance and value of such activities.

> There is an open question

There is a particular question which is still open, i.e. does not have a generally accepted answer.

> The question is “what does it mean to say that a given mathematical statement is true?”

This has at least four layers: (we *ask*) what it *means* to *assert* the *truth* of a *statement*.

- In particular, the assertion may mean nothing, so this question may be taken to include:

  > > “Is it meaningful to say that a given mathematical statement is true?”

> In particular, this question applies to axioms,

since axioms are mathematical statements, given a special status but of the same nature as other statements like theorems, conjectures and fallacies.

#### The question itself

We are asked what (if anything) it means to say that an axiom (like “0 is a natural number” or “adding one to a natural yields another”) or a theorem (like “$2 + 2 = 4$”) *is true*. We may also ask what is the difference between saying “$2 + 2 = 4$” and saying ‘the statement “$2 + 2 = 4$” is true’.

This is different from the way we normally approach mathematics, where we may (for the above examples) start with some perceptions of collections we can count, spot patterns (a collection may be empty, we can add things to it), find a formalism that *seems to correspond to our experience*, and then concentrate largely on the formalism. In other cases our starting point may be perceptions of mathematics itself.

To answer this question, we have to expand our scope to include more than the formalism, and ask what it means to talk about things “corresponding to our experience” or being true in some other sense.

Many views of what mathematics is about and what its statements mean can be found in the [section on ‘Contemporary schools of thought’](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mathematics#Contemporary_schools_of_thought) in the Wikipedia article on the philosophy of mathematics. They include:

- Platonism: mathematical objects have an abstract, absolute reality independent of us.
- Empiricism: we discover mathematics from the experience of our senses.
- Logicism: all mathematics is reducible to, and hence part of, logic.
- Formalism: mathematical statements are only statements about the symbols we manipulate.
- Cognitive theories saying mathematics is not universal, but only exists in human brains.